# Getting font paths to work in CSS in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I can't get the asset pipeline to work with fonts in Rails 4.

I've got `lato-black.eot` in:

```
assets/fonts/lato/lato-black.eot
```

I've got this in `flat-ui.css` (not scss)

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  src: font-path('lato/lato-black.eot');
  src: font-path('lato/lato-black.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), font-path('lato/lato-black.woff') format('woff'), font-path('lato/lato-black.ttf') format('truetype'), font-path('lato/lato-black.svg#latoblack') format('svg');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

I've got this in `config/application.rb`

```
# config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'fonts')
```

EDIT: This doesn't work in the css code:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Lato';
  src:  url(<%= asset_path 'lato/lato-black.eot' %>);
  src:  url(<%= asset_path 'lato/lato-black.eot?#iefix' %>) format('embedded-opentype'),  url(<%= asset_path 'lato/lato-black.woff' %>) format('woff'),  url(<%= asset_path 'lato/lato-black.ttf' %>) format('truetype'),  url(<%= asset_path 'lato/lato-black.svg#latoblack' %>) format('svg');
  font-weight: 900;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Comment: It does not work for development or production env? Are you using LESS or SASS? Did you examine the output of css after less/sass processing?

Comment: I'm not using less or sass. The code above is in a css file. I'm currently working in development.

Comment: These `font-path/font-url` helpers come from LESS/SASS Rails wrappers. If you are not using it, drop it and replace with `url`.

Comment: So I should be using `url('assets/fonts/lato/lato-black.eot')` ?

Comment: I would say rather `url(<%= asset_path 'lato/lato-black.eot' %>)`

Comment: Ehhh... still not working - check the OP.

Comment: I've also tried it with `src:  url(<%= asset_path 'fonts/lato/lato-black.eot' %>);`

Comment: Does Rails serve it correctly? Can you check it `http://localhost:3000/assets/lato/lato-black.eot`?

Comment: Yeah, it's serving correctly at `http://localhost:3000/assets/lato/lato-black.eot`. But when I go into Sources in Chrome and view the source for the css file it is being rendered literally as `src:  url(<%= asset_path 'lato/lato-black.eot' %>);`, not `src: url('/assets/lato/lato-black.eot')`

Comment: It looks like your css file doesn't get precompiled. If you type `rake assets:precompile` - does your css exist within `public/assets` directory?

Answer (score 0):

Try asset-url() instead of font-path()

```
src: asset-url('lato/lato-black.eot');
```

And in your production.rb :

```
# Precompile additional assets
config.assets.precompile += %w( .svg .eot .woff .ttf )
```